# conda searchで見つかるのにconda installするとPackageNotFoundErrorとなる

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

[パッケージ](https://www.earthsystemcog.org/projects/esmpy/releases)をcondaコマンドでインストールを試みています．

`conda search -c nesii esmpy`と打つと

```
Fetching package metadata .............
esmpy                        7.0.0                    py27_1  nesii
```

と見つかるのですが，
`conda install --name py27 --channel nessi esmpy`とすると

```
Fetching package metadata ....
WARNING: The remote server could not find the noarch directory for the
requested channel with url: https://conda.anaconda.org/nessi

It is possible you have given conda an invalid channel. Please double-check
your conda configuration using `conda config --show`.

If the requested url is in fact a valid conda channel, please request that 
the channel administrator create `noarch/repodata.json` and associated
`noarch/repodata.json.bz2` files, even if `noarch/repodata.json` is empty.
$ mkdir noarch
$ echo '{}' > noarch/repodata.json
$ bzip2 -k noarch/repodata.json
.........

PackageNotFoundError: Packages missing in current channels:

- esmpy
```

とエラーが表示されます．
どのように対処すればよいでしょうか？

以下実行環境です
`pyenv versions`は

```
system
anaconda3-5.0.1
* anaconda3-5.0.1/envs/py27 (set by /home/username/pyenv/version)
anaconda3-5.0.1/envs/py36
```

となっており，activateしてpy27の仮想環境に入っています．
ちなみに`pyenv global anaconda3-5.0.1`としてpy27の仮想環境に入って同様に試みたのですが同じエラーメッセージが返ってきました．